# Drupal 7 node reference field formatter for nid

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I'm working in Drupal 7 and using the reference module to attach an node reference to another node. I'm then using views to show some of that nodes fields. When I display the field for the node reference, I'm give the choice of formatting it as a title, title with link, or rendering out the whole node. All I really want to be able to do is render out the nid or the node rather than the title. There were a number of modules that did this in Drupal 6, anyone know how to do it in Drupal 7?

Thanks

Comment: I was glad to find your post. Actually, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Would be pleased to see your patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

having trouble creating the patch, here is what I did, added

```
'node_reference_nid' => array(
  'label'       => t('Nid'),
  'description' => t('Display the nid of the referenced node.'),
  'field types' => array('node_reference'),
),
```

to the node_reference_field_formatter_info() function also added

```
  case 'node_reference_nid':
  foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
    if ($item['access']) {
      $node = $item['node'];
      $result[$delta] = array(
          '#markup' => check_plain($node->nid),
       );
      if (!$node->status) {
        $result[$delta]['#prefix'] = '<span class="node-unpublished">';
        $result[$delta]['#suffix'] = '</span>';
      }
    }
  }
  break;
```

to the node_reference_field_formatter_view() function

that's it, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do this by altering the node_reference module within the references module. If anyone is interested in the patch let me know

Comment: You're encouraged to [answer your own questions here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). You should post a link to patch, write how you solved the problem, and mark the question as solved for future readers.